# Ext JS 4.2.3 define tableAttrs with css class instead of style

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4.2

How can I define tableAttrs with css class instead of style ? 
For example instead of style in this code

```
layout: {
        type: 'table',
        columns: 4,
        tableAttrs: {
            width: '100%',
            style: 'border-collapse:collapse'

        },
        tdAttrs: {
            style: 'vertical-align:middle;height:80px;padding-right:40px;'
        }
    }
```

I want something like

```
layout: {
        type: 'table',
        columns: 4,
        tableAttrs: {
            width: '100%',
            **cls: 'border-style'**

        },
        tdAttrs: {
            **cls: 'cell-style'**
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`itemCls`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Table-cfg-itemCls) attribute

Example:

```
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 4,
    tableAttrs: {
        width: '100%'
    },
    itemCls: 'customClass'
}
```

```css
.customClass {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```